# Links move up on click

Tags: css

I am using Woocommerce plugin for my shopping cart and I have trouble with links and it is only for Woocommerce pages. When I click on a.button div it moves for 4px to the top. I cant find source of this issue. Try to click on thumb or on black button down there.

http://valeka.net/higher/?post_type=product

Can you help me to see what am I missing?

Comment: On Stack Overflow (abbrev.SO) it's good style to show your code in the question not in an external link. Because you'll eventually fix the external link and future visitors will not be able to solve their own problems by reading the answers to this question.

Comment: I just didnt know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a `border-top: 4px` in normal state vs a `border-top: 0px` when `:active` possibly from an inherited reset style sheet for the `:active` state.

For example when disabling the following:

```
.woocommerce a.button,
.woocommerce button.button,
.woocommerce input.button,
...
{
// margin: 0px;
```

The movement seems to not affect the add-to-cart button anymore (but it still affects the product image).

For `button.button` you have:

```
.woocommerce a.button:active,
.woocommerce button.button:active,
.woocommerce input.button:active,
.woocommerce #respond input#submit:active,
.woocommerce #content input.button:active,
.woocommerce-page a.button:active,
.woocommerce-page button.button:active,
.woocommerce-page input.button:active,
.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit:active,
.woocommerce-page #content input.button:active
{
top: 1px;
}
```

Once removed this will stop the `filter` button from moving 1px when active.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tired to edit code as you wrote but still nothing. I still cant find what couse this mess.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

this here is causing the image & button to go up:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:active,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:active {
    margin-top: -1px !important;
}
```

layout-1200.css => line° 2992, disable it, or remove it.

When seeing the name off the CSS file, i guess, you have to do it in an override, or in all CSS (*i think there will be mobile CSS's to*)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but removing or editing those lines didnt help. So I added `.woocommerce ul.products li.product:active .button.add_to_cart_button,
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:focus .button.add_to_cart_button {
 margin-top: 16px !important;
}` And thats how I stop moving buttons when click on image. And you can check buttons on sidebar, they move too.

Comment: as you can see i the code i posted, i was targeting the <li>, no buttons. Also there is no pseudo:focus in my answer. And further, i was referring to margin-top: -1 to be 0 or entirely to be removed. for your sidebar, you know now i what direction to look at.

Comment: I tried that what you said, just for <li>, remove code, enter value 0 and nothing. I was just pointing that class .button can be the problem. Thanks again!